How can I express the idea of counting a number slowly by prolonging it from one point of time to another?
I am teaching my children to meditate.
This is the goal

The child will say the number 1 slowly quietly in his head , not out-loud.
He says "1...1...1" slowly, starting all the way from when he inhales until he exhales. The saying of "1...1..1..1" should go smoothly without any interruption during the process of inhaling and exhaling. Repeat the same process for number 2,3...10.
For example, "count number 1  by prolonging it all the way from when you inhale until you exhale. Repeat the same process for number 2,3 and so on".
How can I express the idea of counting a number slowly by prolonging it from one point of time to another?

I (a native speaker from the US) would say "Draw out each number." When talking to a young child, I might instead say "Say the number in slow-mo" which stands for Slow Motion

Prolonging is taking extra time, like to say sweeeeet. You are repeating the same word to prolong the breath.

This is teaching advice, not English.  Don't express it in words, demonstrate.  Show, don't tell.

Why would you not use your mother tongue with your own child for these type of things? And I agree with James K, you show a small child how things are done; e.g. writing cursive, tie shoe laces, cleaning teeth properly, holding a pencil in their hand etc. Very few native speakers would actually give verbal instructions, many  might talk and demonstrate at the same time, most will just demonstrate and praise their child to encourage them.

@Mari-LouA, I am teaching her bilingually. It's incredibly hard if you are not a native English speaker

I thought you meant take a deep breath and then say outloud "one" slowly again and again until you run out of breath.

Use a held musical note analogy.

If English is not your mother tongue at home, and you said you are not a native speaker, without knowing it you might be instilling errors in your children's language acquisition. Be careful about what you teach, focus on the most common vocabulary and structures and be very careful about the pronunciation, too.  Make sure you're stressing the right syllables.  Consider hiring a  student native speaker to give private tuition at home, and ask him or her to make the lessons fun, so your kids will find English fun.

And when they require punishment, you can force them to sit still as you read them a passage from H&P.

@Mari-LouA, hiring is a student native speaker is expensive. I try to make sure to say sentences from dictionaries and double check the pronunciation before saying. My daughter also talks English with some of her friends who are kind of half-native English speakers (their mom is Vietnamese and dad is English)

OP's query on mindful breathing techniques

How can I express the idea of counting a number slowly by prolonging it from one point of time to another?

If I understand correctly, OP is trying to teach the child breathing techniques during meditation. The terms used for this are mindfulness and  mindful breathing
Ref. Cambridge dictionary.

mindfulness.
noun [ U ]
the practice of being aware of your body, mind, and feelings in the present moment, thought to create a feeling of calm:

There are several breathing exercises. "Counted breathing" is one of them.
But I didn't quite understand the counting technique OP tried to explain through the diagram.  The part I didn't understand is

He says "1...1...1" slowly, starting all the way from when he inhales until he exhales.

Normally we count 1-2-3-4 to check the inhaling time and the exhaling time.
For example a counted breathing can be.
1. Inhale for a count of 4.
2. Hold your breath for a count of 4..
3. Exhale for a count of 4..
4. Hold your breath again for a count of 4
Please check if the counted breathing exercises in this link are helpful:
https://www.verywellmind.com/how-to-reduce-stress-with-breathing-exercises-3144508

We can't possibly start counting during the inhalation stage.  The entire counting process for a number is in the exhalation stage.
Take a deep breath.  Start counting 'one' slowly from the moment you start to exhale and prolong it until the end of the exhalation.  Repeat for 'two' and so on up to '10'.

I mean "count in my head" not "count outloud"

Alright, if we're counting in our heads, the process can start anytime.
